# Ruby Regexp: How do I replace doubly escaped characters such as \\n with \n

Tags: ruby, regex

So, I have

```
puts "test\\nstring".gsub(/\\n/, "\n")
```

and that works.

But how do I write one statement that replaces \n, \r, and \t with their correctly escaped counterparts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't escaped characters, those are literal characters that are only represented as being escaped so they're human readable. What you need to do is this:

```
escapes = {
  'n' => "\n",
  'r' => "\r",
  't' => "\t"
}

"test\\nstring".gsub(/\\([nrt])/) { escapes[$1] }
# => "test\nstring"
```

You will have to add other escape characters as required, and this still won't accommodate some of the more obscure ones if you really need to interpret them all. A potentially dangerous but really simple solution is to just eval it:

```
eval("test\\nstring")
```

So long as you can be assured that your input stream doesn't contain things like `#{ ... }` that would allow injecting arbitrary Ruby, which is possible if this is a one shot repair to fix some damaged encoding, this would be fine.

**Update**

There might be a mis-understanding as to what these backslashes are. Here's an example:

```
"\n".bytes.to_a
# => [10]

"\\n".bytes.to_a
# => [92, 110]
```

You can see these are two entirely different things. `\n` is a representation of ASCII character 10, a linefeed.

Comment: Something looks wrong with the result ....                   "test\\nstring".gsub(/\\([ntr])/) { |s| escapes[s[1]] }
# => "testn\nstring"

Comment: this just removes the \\? characters... =\

Comment: It doesn't remove the characters, it replaces `\\n` which is a literal backslash followed by an `n` with `\n` which is a newline character.

Comment: sorry bro.  
>> escapes = {'n' => "\n", 't' => "\t"}  
=> {"n"=>"\n", "t"=>"\t"}  
>> "test\\nstri\\tng".gsub(/\\([nrt])/) { |s| escapes[s[1]] }  
=> "teststring"  
  
but It just removes them. No white space characters at all.

Comment: If you're using Ruby 1.8 you may need to substitute `s[1]` with `$1`.

Comment: $1 doesn't work. It just puts $1 into the string, as I said in @black's  answer

Comment: I updated my answer with `$1` instead of `s[1]` and it works in Ruby 1.9 and Ruby 1.8 if you paste that in to `irb`. @black's answer is completely different, using `$1` as an argument and not as a value inside a block. If you pass it in as a value it is interpreted before the `gsub` method is called, instead of being evaluated on each substitution.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use backreferences. Try

```
puts "test\\nstring".gsub(/(\\[nrt])/, $1)
```

gsub sets `$n` (where 'n' is the number of the corresponding group in the regular expression used) to the content matched the pattern.

**EDIT:**
I modified the regexp, now the output should be:

```
test\nstring
```

The `\n` won't be intepreted as newline by puts.

Comment: the dollar sign doesnt work =\ I get this (when I copy pasted): test$1stri$1ng

Comment: This doesn't do anything useful. The result is `test$1string`.

Comment: This is still producing nothing useful. You can't use `$1` like that, it must be exercised within a block. When you're working with data like this, you should always use `puts` in conjunction with `inspect` to see the actual string being produced.

Answer (score 1):

through the help of @tadman, and @black, I've discovered the solution:

```
>> escapes = {'\\n' => "\n", '\\t' => "\t"}
=> {"\\t"=>"\t", "\\n"=>"\n"}
>> "test\\nstri\\tng".gsub(/\\([nrt])/) { |s| escapes[s] }
=> "test\nstri\tng"
>> puts "test\\nstri\\tng".gsub(/\\([nrt])/) { |s| escapes[s] }
test
stri    ng
=> nil
```

as it turns out, ya just map the \\ to \ and all is good. Also, you need to use puts for the terminal to output the whitespace correctly.

```
 escapes = {'\\n' => "\n", '\\t' => "\t"}
puts "test\\nstri\\tng".gsub(/\\([nrt])/) { |s| escapes[s] }
```